# Printing auto generated WS client response

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I auto generated WS client from WSDL file (using eclipse).

I am using this client to invoke a method, for example:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    try{
        object view = proxy.invokeEndPoint(input);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This call invokes the operation and gives me a result (for HTTP it suppose to return a xml).

How do i get the entire xml response.

In reality i get an object (view) which can contain many other objects, how do i get the raw xml response?

Comment: which webservices library do you use?

Comment: I am using Eclipse built in - not sure what library it uses

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to see the XML for debugging there is a very simple [SOAPMonitor](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/soapmonitor-user-guide.html) in Apache Axis, which can be used as a proxy to view SOAP requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

I guass the only solution is to overide the ToString method of the return object 
and manually build the String.

Answer (score 0):

Use **socat** linux command

A example: http://qbit.com.mx/blog/2014/02/13/como-debuguear-un-cliente-de-webservice-java/